# Find point of contact when tangent and circle equations are given.

Tags: circles, tangent-line

If $L=lx+my+n=0$ is tangent to circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ then find point of contact.

I know that equation of tangent is $S_{1}=xx_1+yy_1+g(x+x_1)+f(y+y_1)+c=0$
anf rearranging I obtain $S_1=(g+x_1)x+(f+y_1)y + gx_1+fy_1+c=0$.

By comparing coefficients it should give the point of contact: $x_1=l-g$, $y_1=m-f$. But when I use this method in exercise it gives me wrong a point of contact.

Where I am going wrong? Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear equations $L=0$ and $S_1=0$ are equivalent iff the coefficients are proportional. So, you should use the equations
$$\frac{g+x_1}{l}=\frac{f+y_1}{m}=\frac{gx_1+fy_1+c}{n},$$
and by solving the linear system
$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{g+x_1}{l}=\frac{f+y_1}{m}\\
\displaystyle\frac{gx_1+fy_1+c}{n}=\frac{f+y_1}{m}
\end{cases}$$
that is
$$\begin{cases}
mx_1-ly_1=lf-mg\\
mgx_1+(mf-n)y_1=nf-mc
\end{cases}$$
we find
$$x_1 = \frac{lf^2-mgf+ng-lc}{lg+mf-n}\quad,\quad
y_1 = \frac{mg^2-lfg+nf-mc}{lg+mf-n}.$$

Comment: Looks correct. But I wonder why that equation is used.

Comment: The linear equations $L=0$ and $S_1=0$ are equivalent if the coefficients are proportional.

Comment: @Fawad Any further doubts?

Comment: Nope. I understood. Another way to solve is that point of contact is foot of perpendicular to centre of circle on tangent line. In equation of foot of perpendicular all variables are known except point of contact. Both gives same equation. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Z can you please explain how you get the 2nd line? I understand the proportional coefficients part, but how did you get the 2nd line?

Comment: @F.N. I just solved the linear system. See my edit.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks you so much.